# Vector bundle nonvanishing section

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I'm stuck with something I've been trying to prove:

> A tautological 1-dim vector bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}P^n$ is given, where $E\subset \mathbb{R}P^n \times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a subset of pairs $([x_1,...x_{n+1}],v)$, such that $v\in[x_1,...x_{n+1}].$ Note: $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is a $n$-dimensional projective space, elements of which we denote as $[x_1,...,x_n].$

**I want to show that there are no global non-vanishing section $s:\mathbb{R} P^n\rightarrow E$, such that $s(m)\neq 0$, for all $m\in\mathbb{R}P^n$.**

My thinking (I'm a total beginner, please be kind):

$E\subset \mathbb{R}P^n \times\mathbb{R}^{n+1} $ probably means that $E$ is a (vector) subspace of $\mathbb{R}P^n \times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, meaning that it has to contain a $0$ (vector). We know that the global section is defined such that $\pi \circ s=I_{d|\mathbb{R} P^n}$, in order for this composition to work $s(m)$ needs to be $s(m)=0$ for some $m\in\mathbb{R} P^n$, otherwise the codomain of $s:\mathbb{R} P^n\rightarrow E$ and the domain of $\pi$ above don't match and we can't have $\pi \circ s$:

On my second try, I tried to use the fact that sections are smooth maps and maybe deduct something useful, but to no avail.

**I would really appreciate some help.**

**EDIT**: as someone in the comments suggested my terminology regarding the vector (sub)space is wrong, the correct term would be (sub)bundle.

Comment: $E$ can't be a vector subspace of $\mathbb{RP}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ as the latter is not a vector space. The correct terminology is that $E$ is a subbundle of the vector bundle $\mathbb{RP}^n\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you, I will add this to my question!

Comment: Let $E^1$ denote the pairs $(x,v)\in E$ with $\|v\| = 1$ (in the usual Euclidean norm).  Can you show that $\pi|_{E^1}:E^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$ is a non-trivial two fold covering?  Can you show that if there is a non-zero section $s$ of $E$, then there is a section with image in $E^1$?  Can you use all this to conclude what you want?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you! I will try to prove the above by means of what you've suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your section $s$. It corresponds to a unique map $\widetilde{s}:\Bbb S^n \to \Bbb R^{n+1}$, such that $\widetilde{s}(-x)=\widetilde{s}(x)$ and $\widetilde{s}(x)\in \Bbb R x$ for all $x$. This means you can write $\widetilde{s}(x)=\mu(x)x$, where $\mu:\Bbb S^n\to \Bbb R$ corresponds uniquely to $\widetilde{s}$ (and hence $s$) and satisfies $\mu(-x)=-\mu(x)$ for all $x$. By Borsuk-Ulam there is $x_0\in\Bbb S^n$ with $\mu(x_0)=\mu(-x_0)$. So $\mu(x_0)=0$ and so $s(\Bbb R x_0)=0$ as wanted.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on: "Take your section $s$. It corresponds to a unique map $\widetilde{s}:\Bbb S^n \to \Bbb R^{n+1}$, such that $\widetilde{s}(-x)=\widetilde{s}(x)$ and $\widetilde{s}(x)\in \Bbb R x$ for all $x$." 

Is there a theorem that guarantees this?

Comment: $\Bbb R P^n = \Bbb S^n/\Bbb Z_2$, so functions defined on $\Bbb R P^n$ correspond to functions defined on $\Bbb S^n$ which are constant on the $\Bbb Z_2$-orbits $\{x,-x\}$, while $\widetilde{s}(x)\in \Bbb R x$ is because $s$ is a section of the tautological bundle (as opposed to a general section of the trivial bundle).

Comment: thank you! I think I get it now. Sry for the late reply, needed some time to think this through. Just one more thing (to check my understanding): Could it be possible to construct a similar 1-dim bundle, such that $\tilde{E}\rightarrow S^n$ and maybe define a non-vanishing section there?

Comment: No problem, math takes time. For the second question, yes, of course: take $E=\Bbb R {\rm P}^n \times \Bbb R\to \Bbb R{\rm P}^n$ and $s(L)=(L,1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had misunderstood the question: you mean setting $E_x = \Bbb R x$ for $x \in \Bbb S^n$? $s(x)=x$ is a non-vanishing section. In fact, whenever $\mu:\Bbb S^n \to \Bbb R$ is non-vanishing, $x\mapsto \mu(x)x$ does the trick. Passing from $\Bbb R{\rm P}^n$ to $\Bbb S^n$ removed the requirement that $\mu$ is odd, so Borsuk-Ulam doesn't give anything interesting. In fact, this $E$ is just the normal bundle of the sphere (and if you think of differential geometry, I just gave you a unit normal field along $\Bbb S^n$).

Comment: And again many thanks! This really helps!